# universal cover copies of RP2 identified along nontrivial curve

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let X be two copies of RP2 glued along a nontrivial curve in each.  I have determined that X can be represented by two disks (each with opposite points identified) glued along a 1-simplex and calculated that the fundamental group is Z/2Z, therefore the universal cover should have two copies of X.  I think this should be two copies of S2, one inside the other, glued along their equators.  I am not comfortable with this conclusion and am not sure if it is the right one.

Comment: Your description seems correct to me.

Comment: How do I know that I obtained the right space?  What questions do I ask myself?  What am I looking for in addition to a trivial fundamental group?

Comment: You need 1) $\pi_1(Y) = 0$ and that 2) there is a covering map $Y \to X$ in order to show that $Y$ is the universal cover of $X$. (I'm not sure that's the right conditions in full generality but if $X$ is locally contractible I believe it's enough).